# How can I fix a bouncing section/ content while scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scrollmagic

When I scroll down or up I have a section where I use scroll magic on it, and whenever I'm scrolling this section at some point is starting to jump until I reach the `transform:translateY(0)` the position where I want it to be.

And I don't know how to fix it, it is because of the transition? or what?

Any of you ran into something like that?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Init ScrollMagic
  var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

  // build a scene
  var ourScene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
      triggerElement: '.section__students'
    })
    .setClassToggle('.section__students', 'fade-in') // add a class to section__students
    .addIndicators({
      name: 'fade scene',
      colorTrigger: 'transparent',
      indent: 200,
      colorStart: 'transparent'
    }) // this requires a plugin
    .addTo(controller);
});
```

```css
.students-main {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(-350px);
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
}

.section__students.fade-in {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.carousel {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.carousel__button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  transform: translateY(-45%);
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
}

.carousel__button:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.carousel__button--left {
  left: 3.5rem;
  z-index: 1;
}

.carousel__button--right {
  right: 3.5rem;
}

.arrow-left-students {
  font-size: 3rem;
}

.arrow-left-students:hover {
  color: $color-primary;
}

.arrow-right-students {
  font-size: 3rem;
}

.arrow-right-students:hover {
  color: $color-primary;
}

.carousel__nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 3rem 0;
}

.carousel__indicator {
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 1.6rem;
  height: 1.6rem;
  background: $color-gray-dark-2;
  margin: 0 1.2rem;
}

.carousel__indicator:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

section .students-h1 {
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -140px);
}

.students-h1::after {
  content: '';
  width: 10rem;
  height: .8rem;
  background-color: $color-primary-light;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -24rem;
  top: 70%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 30px);
  border-radius: 2rem;
}

.wrap-students {
  display: inline-block;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 3rem;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 30rem;
  width: 30rem;
  background-color: $color-grey-light-1;
  border-radius: 3rem;
}

.wrap-students:hover {
  box-shadow: -1px 3px 20px 3px $color-primary-light;
  transform: translateY(-10%);
  transition: all .5s;
}

.students {
  padding: 2.5rem 6rem;
}

.students .students-name {
  color: $color-gray-dark-2;
  padding-top: 1rem;
}

.students .students-description {
  margin-top: .5rem;
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: "lato", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}

.wrap-students .students .students-img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 16rem;
  height: 16rem;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: 50% 10%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.7/ScrollMagic.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.7/plugins/debug.addIndicators.min.js"></script>
<section class="section__students students-main">
  <div id="parallax__carousel" class="carousel">

    <button class="carousel__button carousel__button--left">
                    <i class="fas fa-chevron-left arrow-left-students"></i>
    </button>


    <h1 class="students-h1">Students</h1>

    <div class="wrap-students">
      <div class="students">
        <img class="students-img" src="/img/student1.jpg" alt="student-image">
        <h2 class="students-name">Nick Harrison</h2>
        <p class="students-description">Lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="wrap-students">
      <div class="students">
        <img class="students-img" src="/img/student3.jpg" alt="student-image">
        <h2 class="students-name">Nick Harrison</h2>
        <p class="students-description">Lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="wrap-students">
      <div class="students">
        <img class="students-img" src="/img/student1.jpg" alt="student-image">
        <h2 class="students-name">Nick Harrison</h2>
        <p class="students-description">Lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="wrap-students">
      <div class="students">
        <img class="students-img" src="/img/student3.jpg" alt="student-image">
        <h2 class="students-name">Nick Harrison</h2>
        <p class="students-description">Lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <button class="carousel__button carousel__button--right">
                    <i class="fas fa-chevron-right arrow-right-students"></i>
                </button>

    <div class="carousel__nav">
      <button class="carousel__indicator"></button>
      <button class="carousel__indicator"></button>
      <button class="carousel__indicator"></button>
    </div>

  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: can you do a minimum reproducible snippet so users can see what you see

Comment: Indeed, and add version numbers of the libraries you are using please.

Comment: I'm using these CDNs  /    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.7/ScrollMagic.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.7/plugins/debug.addIndicators.min.js"></script>

Comment: How can i do that snippet like a screen record or what?

Comment: I fixed the snippet in de question

Comment: So what did you do , cause i can't see what you've done ...?

Comment: I only copied your code snippets in a SO snippet and added the right CDN's.. the question itself is not fixed. We can hopefully see what you see now.

Comment: Oh, I see ... yeah but it ain't actually what I see now , the question is simple how can i fix a jumping element / section or anything when scrolling , because until it reach the right position while scrolling if i stop scrolling between the positions this section starts to jump like a yo-yo  ...

Comment: It's more like bouncing ....

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused purely because of your CSS.

When you want to transition element position on hover you should or the best practice is to target the hover selector of the element's parent.

Here's working [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/5u4n18qg/)

```
.wrap-students .students {
  transition: all .5s;
}

.wrap-students:hover .students { 
  transform: translateY(-10%);
}
```

Comment: This didn't solve the problem ... I have tried even to remove the transition from the students class but still nothing , anyway thanks.

Comment: You've missed the point. The problem was not the transition. You're moving the same element you're hovering. **The solution is to hover the parent and move the child**. As you can see in the demo https://jsfiddle.net/5u4n18qg/ there's no jittering /bouncing and it's your own code I've used just changed the CSS a bit.